# Limitations of objects in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, object

Why would a partial view display objects correctly but calling the same function to populate a viewmodel returns nulls?

Class example Model:

```
[DisplayColumn("OrganizationName")] 
public class Organization
{
    public  int OrganizationId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Organization Name"), MaxLength(75), Required]
    public  string OrganizationName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Positions")]
    public int? PositionId { get; set; } 
    [Display(Name = "OrganizationSupervisor")]
    public int? OrganizationSupervisorId { get; set; }
    public virtual Organization PrimaryParentOrg { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "All Positions")]
    public virtual ICollection<Position> OrgPositions { get; set; } 
    [ForeignKey("OrganizationSupervisorId")]
    [InverseProperty("Orgs")]
    public virtual OrganizationSupervisor Supervisor { get; set; } 
}
public class OrganizationSupervisor
{
    [Key]
    public int OrganizationSupervisorId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public  Position SupervisorPos { get; set; }
    public int? OrganizationId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("OrganizationId")]
    public virtual ICollection<Organization> Orgs { get; set; }
}
public class Position
{
    public int PositionId { get; set; }
    public string DefaultTitle { get; set; }    
}
```

//     Function that is failing:

```
public class fcns
{
    private static Position getEmpPosSup(Position EmpPos, Organization Org, ref int Cnt)
    {
        Position PosSup = null;
        Cnt++;
        if ((EmpPos != null) && (Org != null))
        {
            if (Org.Supervisor != null)
                if (Org.Supervisor.SupervisorPos != null)
                    if (EmpPos != Org.Supervisor.SupervisorPos)
                        PosSup = Org.Supervisor.SupervisorPos;
            if (PosSup == null && Cnt < 3)
            {
                //  Try the next level up, up to 3 times then give up
                PosSup = getEmpPosSup(EmpPos, Org.PrimaryParentOrg, ref Cnt);
            }
        }
        return PosSup;
    }
}
```

The function returns the position of the supervisor for the position submitted relative to the organization specified.

Comment: My first reaction is: Please use better method/class/variable names.  It's very hard to determine what you're trying to do.  (This isn't an answer, so leaving it as a comment)

Comment: Can you post your view code as well, or part of it. How are you calling this function?

Comment: *// Function that is failing:* in what way is the function failing?

Comment: how doy you call it and what's the result you are getting in both scenarios?

Comment: Why not condense those if statements. +1 to Pheonixblad9 for the type name suggestion. The code could be much more readable.

Comment: @BrianLegg the partial view uses it like: EmpPosSup = getEmpPosSup(Pos, Org); then passes it to a partial to display it: @Html.Partial("_Pos", EmpPosSup), the viewmodel calls it to set a field in the view model.  The difference is calling it from the view yeilds a value and calling it from the controller does not.

Comment: Actually calling it from the controller will yield a result, too if you debug it and interegate the data each step through the function.  It makes no sense why interegating the data or displaying the result in a view would work.  The only differnce is that there is time consumed in a view model and debugging process...

Comment: I'm not sure why this would work when you debug but doesn't work at runtime (so I'm not adding this as an answer) but I suspect it has to do with the way EF lazy loads data for your virtual properties. Specifically Organization.PrimaryParentOrg. You're accessing this property Org -> parent -> parent -> parent -> etc multiple levels deep potentially. EF doesn't handle this very well unless you have "include"ed these properties on retrieval. How are you pulling in the Organization you pass to this method? Any other details you can give?

Comment: @BrianLegg If I could figure out how to give you credit for the answer I would.

Answer (score 0):

@BrianLegg

You were right, thank you for the suggestion.  The problem was Lazy Loading or something like it.  The solution I found that seems to always work is to use the repository function AllIncluding(...) instead of the All function.  For example I used:

```
IQueryable<OrganizationSupervisor> lstOrgSups = organizationsupervisorRepository.AllIncluding(organizationsupervisor => organizationsupervisor.SupervisorPos);
```

This seems to force EF to return the SupervisorPos Position object that was returning null if not interrogated during a debugging session.